# The select in materialize css is not behaving as expected when added dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery, pug, materialize

I am trying to add options dynamically to a select in materialize css.It queries teamname from mongodb and adds them.But the list options is staying stable,it shows up but vanishes fast.This is not the case with usual select,it stays until one option is selected.Please correct me or guide me to overcome this issue.

```
 doctype html
    head
      title Register
      // Import Google Icon Font
      link(href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons', rel='stylesheet')
      // Import materialize.css
      // Compiled and minified CSS
      link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css')
      // Let browser know website is optimized for mobile
      meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
    .card-panel.hoverable.container
      .row
        form#reg_project.col.s12(method='POST', action='/projects/reg_project')
          .row
            .col.s12
              br
              br
              h6#q2.center-align
                | Bravo! It always seems impossible until it&apos;s done.
              h5#q1.center-align
                | Never give up,just keep going #{user.username}
              br
              hr(style='width: 250px;')
              br
              .row
                h5.center-align It&apos;s not about ideas.It&apos;s about making ideas happen
              h6#q1.center-align Wee! Let&apos;s build the future
              br
              br
            .row
              .col.s6
                .input-field.col.s12
                  input#name.validate(type='text', name='name' value=username)
                  label(for='name') Name
                  span.helper-text(data-error='Oops,fill me', data-success='cool,nice name champ!')
              .col.s6
                .input-field.col.s12
                  select(name='dep')
                    option(value='', disabled='', selected='') Department
                    option(value='1') MECH
                    option(value='2') CIVIL
                    option(value='3') CSE
                    option(value='4') EEE
                    option(value='5') ECE
                    option(value='6') MCA
                    option(value='7') OTHERS
                  label Home of your passion
            .row
              .col.s6
                .input-field.col.s12
                  input#email.validate(type='email', name='email' value=email)
                  label(for='email') Email
                  span.helper-text(data-error='Oops!you missed me', data-success='Cheers!email ok')
              .col.s6
                .input-field.col.s12
                  select(name='yr')
                    option(value='', disabled='', selected='') YEAR
                    option(value='8') FIRST YEAR
                    option(value='9') SECOND YEAR
                    option(value='10') THIRD YEAR
                    option(value='11') FOURTH YEAR
                  label Bootstrapping my
            .row
              .col.s6
                p
                  label.col.s6
                    input.with-gap(name='position', type='radio', value='team', checked='')
                    span Team
                  label.col.s6
                    input.with-gap(name='position', type='radio', value='individual')
                    span Lone Wolf
              .col.s6
                p
                  // Switch
                  label.col.s6 Join hands with my peers
                  .switch
                    label
                      | Yes
                      input#button1(type='checkbox')
                      span.lever
                      |                 No
            .row
              #hide.col.s6
                #test.input-field.col.s12
                  select(name='teamname' id='teamname')


                    // dynamic insertion
                  label Registered teams
              #div1.col.s6(style='display: none;')
                .input-field.col.s12
                  input#teamname.validate(type='text', name='teamname')
                  label(for='teamname') Team Name
                  span.helper-text(data-error='Oops,fill me or try to revert back to pick one', data-success='cool,all the best!')
              .col.s6
                .input-field.col.s12
                  input#project_title.validate(type='text', name='project_title' required)
                  label(for='project_title') Your project title
                  span.helper-text(data-error='Oops,fill me', data-success='Wow,all the best yar!')
            .row
              .col.s6
                .input-field.col.s12
                  textarea#project_description.materialize-textarea.validate(name='project_description' required)
                  label(for='project_description') Project Description
                  span.helper-text(data-error='Ahem,please tell us about your project', data-success='Super cool!')
              .col.s6
                br
                // Switch
                label.col.s6 Have prior project experience in THIRAN
                .switch
                  label
                    | Yes 
                    input#button2(type='checkbox', name='experience')
                    span.lever
                    |             No
            br
            .row
              .col.s6.div2
                .input-field.col.s12
                  input#pre_project_title.validate(type='text', name='pre_project_title')
                  label(for='pre_project_title') Previous project title
                  span.helper-text(data-error='Oops,please fill it', data-success='Impressive')
              .col.s6.div2
                .input-field.col.s12
                  textarea#pre_project_description.materialize-textarea.validate(name='pre_project_description')
                  label(for='pre_project_description') Description
                  span.helper-text(data-error='Ahem,few words please', data-success='Great job!')
            .row
              .col.s12.div2
                .input-field.col.s12
                  textarea#feedback.materialize-textarea(name='feedback')
                  label(for='feedback') Feedback
                  span.helper-text(data-error='Ahem,your feedbacks help us serve better', data-success='Thanks champ!')
                  small Share a few words about your experience in thiran
            .row
              .col.s6
                p
                  label
                    input#button3(type='checkbox', name='mentor', checked='')
                    span Mentor needed
                    br
                    small Uncheck if not needed
              #div3.col.s6
                .input-field.col.s12
                  input#phoneno.validate(type='text', name='phoneno')
                  label(for='phoneno') Contact no
                  span.helper-text(data-error="Ahem,we couldn't help you much without sufficient contact no", data-success='Done,we will contact you soon')
          .row
            .center-align
              input.btn.btn-primary(type='submit', value='Submit')
    script(type='text/javascript', src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js')
    // Compiled and minified JavaScript
    script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js')
    script(src='/js/main.js') 
    script(type='text/javascript').
```

and my jquery to add options in main.js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#test').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url:'/projects/getprojects/',
    method:"GET",
    success:function(response){

      response.forEach(function(project){
          $("#teamname").formSelect();
        $('#teamname').prepend(

            '<option value='+project.teamname+'>'+project.teamname+'</option>\
            ')



        console.log(project.teamname);
      });
    }
  });
  })
});
```

Comment: Is there any one free to help me,I couldn't work further.Two more forms requires same functionality.

Comment: I tried to console.log the queried items it comes fine,why it is not getting appended or prepended to the select class.Please help

Comment: What materialize are you using? and what version? (There are many implementations, such as https://materializecss.com/select.html or https://getmdl.io/ )

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding,the version I am using is 1.0.0-rc.2 .I was just following the example given in the official documentation,but trying to add options dynamically.I will leave the documentation link too https://materializecss.com/select.html

Answer (score 0):

After appending `<option>` elements you need to use the following:

```
M.FormSelect.init(document.getElementById("teamname"))
```

Or with Jquery

```
$("#teamname").formSelect()
```

You should also avoid calling `.formSelect()` until all the options are appended.

```
response.forEach(function(project){
  $('#teamname').prepend('<option value='+project.teamname+'>'+project.teamname+'</option>\')
  console.log(project.teamname);
});
$("#teamname").formSelect();
```

Comment: It's working now but the options are displaying just a second.It shows up but vanishes before selecting.The UI is similar to ordinary materialize css select.html,but it's not staying or behaving as expected .Why?Due to the server side I was not able to add jsfiddle.Please help.

Comment: `M.FormSelect.init(document.getElementById("teamname"))` should go after the `.forEach` loop, I think. It might be a timing issue otherwise.
Also, you may want to call `document.getElementById("teamname").destroy();` before the `.init` if you have already initialized it before, but it doesn't sound like you would need to do that.

Comment: Tried adding it,see above code for changes.Timing issue in the sense?Is there a way to rectify them.Any way to make it stand stable until selecting one from the list of options?

Comment: If I define the class as browser-default it works fine.It is not stable only when I tried to apply the materialize styles.Why?For now I am using as browser-default,but there must be a way to do so,right?

Comment: See the code I posted. your `.formSelect()` should be outside the `forEach` I think